# Is Big Hero 6 supposed to be set in an alternate universe or the near future of our universe?

Tags: big-hero-6

The movie is set in a city called San Fransokyo that looks very similar to San Francisco, but with many more persons of Japanese descent.

Is the movie supposed to be set in an alternate universe or the near future of our universe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [*The Art of Big Hero 6*](https://archive.org/details/the-art-of-big-hero-6_202302/Jessica%20Julius%20-%20The%20Art%20of%20Big%20Hero%206-Chronicle%20Books%20%282014%29/) (p. 19):

> DON WANTED TO FIGURE OUT A LOGICAL EXPLANATION FOR HOW A MASH-UP CITY LIKE THIS COULD EXIST. I CAME UP WITH IDEA THAT, AFTER THE 1906 EARTHQUAKE IN SAN FRANCISCO, JAPANESE IMMIGRANTS REBUILT THE PLACE USING TECHNIQUES THAT ALLOW MOVEMENT AND FLEXIBILITY IN A SEISMIC EVENT.

> SCOTT WATANABE, *ART DIRECTOR, ENVIRONMENTS*

More (p. 16):

> The idea to combine two iconic cities into one unique setting started with executive producer John Lasseter. “I challenged them to come up with something new and different, to find their own mythical city.” The filmmakers agreed, but wanted to retain elements of the Japanese style, so director Don Hall began to think about a place he could blend with Tokyo in a fun, fresh way. “I chose San Francisco because Los Angeles didn’t feel right, and New York is the epicenter of the Marvel comics world, which I wanted to move away from. San Francisco has so many distinctive features—the Golden Gate Bridge, the hills, the painted ladies, the cable cars—that when we mashed it up with Japanese aesthetics, it led to a lot of exciting possibilities. It was familiar but not the obvious choice.”